# How and where to insert the Sql Db query while adding searchview in android?

Tags: android, searchview

I want a make a search view in android which reads values from sqlite db and show as list view when we change text of my searchview.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that a have defined a EditText to get the user input.

then use this to hook for the text change event and then run a database query to construct suggestions and then add them to your list view:

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        doSomething();
    } 
});
```

Comment: I was asking for where to write the query?

Comment: Inside afterTextChanged() function.